# java stream extending collectors and disabling combiner

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I had extended the collector but my requirement is that my logic demands that collection grouping (accumulation) requires it must not use the combiner what should be the logic in combiner to achieve the same.

```
private class XCollector implements Collector<String, TreeSet<String>, TreeSet<String>> {

    XCollector(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<TreeSet<String>> supplier() {
        return TreeSet<String>::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<TreeSet<String>, String> accumulator() {

        return (sortedSet, str) -> {
            some logic
        };

    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<TreeSet<String>> combiner() {
        return (first, second) -> {
            first.addAll(second);
            return first;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<TreeSet<String>, TreeSet<String>> finisher() {
        return (sortedSet) -> {
            System.out.println(sortedSet);
            return sortedSet;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }

}
```

Comment: How and why can't you use a combiner?

Comment: I want to accumulate the elements based on some logic on preceeding and subsequent elements values.So, If i combine 2 sets it may disturb that logic. so i dont need to merge 2 collections i just want to accumulate.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong tools. Either use `reduce()` or don't use streams at all.

Comment: you are correct. removing streams.

Comment: @shmosel not necessarily, you *could* throw an Exception inside the combiner... And you can't use `reduce` without combiner if you want to reduce to a *different type*

Comment: @Eugene Not necessarily what? If you have to throw an exception in the combiner, you're misusing streams.

Comment: what does `some logic` do actually? And why are you doing a custom collector to collect to a `TreeSet`?

Comment: @Eugene some logic: each element compares with previous element and calculate the distance from earlier elements if it is in some multiple then group both of them. ok forget the logic i want to check if the previous element is 1 less than the present if so group otherwise add that element as separate item and so on.

Comment: How does the accumulator know the previous element in your example code? And what does “grouping” mean if your result is just a `TreeSet<String>`?

Comment: Combiners are only used on parallel streams. If you can guarantee that the stream being collected is always sequential, then just throw some runtime exception from within the combiner. But document this fact clearly, or make your stream `.sequential()` before collecting.